# How to use describe keypsaces; command in jupyter notebook

Tags: cassandra, jupyter-notebook

I am reading Cassandra database data in Jupiter notebook. In Cassandra we can use this with command "describe keyspaces;".

Suppose, once I am Jupyter is connected Cassandra and I dont want to use Cassandra, want to input Cassandra commands through Jupyter notebook, how to achieve describe keyspaces in order to know the keyspaces

Tried entering describe keyspaces; command

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])  # provide contact points and port
session = cluster.connect('fiirstkeyspace')
rows = session.execute('select * from books_by_author limit 5 ;')
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

In the above code, I know I have a keyspace called 'fiirstkeyspace'

however,I want to know all the keyspaces in Cassandra through Jupyter notebook.

```
show keyspaces;
  File "<ipython-input-62-dd2f479cd0fc>", line 1
    show keyspaces;
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax



describe keyspaces;
 File "<ipython-input-67-21f5033a29b3>", line 1
    describe keyspaces;
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try this query `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`describe keyspaces`, etc. are commands that are implemented in cqlsh - they aren't real CQL commands.  In Python you can get all this information via [Metadata class](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/metadata.html#schemas), that hides implementation details, as schema for system tables could differ between versions.

The code for getting names of all keyspaces is quite simple (`cluster` is the name of object that you created to connect to Cassandra cluster):

```py
cluster.metadata.keyspaces.keys()
```

And then you can fetch data about individual keyspaces from `cluster.metadata.keyspaces` map.

Comment: This is the exact thing I was looking for

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing, is it possible to get tables under keyspaces? or we need to get it manually by Describe tables; in cassandra? can we also do it through jupyter? I have visited the link you posted above, but , could not get the desired result for table.      I tried cluster.metadata.keyspaces.tables()

Comment: You need to get specific keyspace from map by name, and then get tables from individual keyspace instance